# Android, "R's" rojas en todo el código

Tags: android

Tengo un código el cual traté de compilar por primera vez, y cuando ya estaba a punto de compilar me mandó dos errores:

> Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file crunching failed, see logs
> for details
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

Éste es mi código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageView img;
    Button immg;
    private final int PICKER = 1;
    String encodedImage,foto,funcion;
    DataConnctcion dc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        immg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        immg.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_send) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        PickFile();
    }
    private void PickFile(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Instale un administrador de archivos."), PICKER);
        }catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex){

        }
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int sesultCode, Intent data){
        switch (requestCode){
            case PICKER:
                if (requestCode == RESULT_OK){
                    foto = "foto";
                    Bitmap photobmp;
                    Uri selectdImageUri = data.getData();
                    String dataFU = getRealPathFromURI(selectdImageUri);
                    photobmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(dataFU);
                    img.setImageBitmap(photobmp);
                    
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                           photobmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,88,baos);
                    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
                                            encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri){
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }finally {
            if (cursor != null){
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

¿Me podrían decir por qué se dan estos errores y cómo los puedo solucionar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Los `R` rojos que indicas, se generan cuando existe un problema en los recursos**, por ejemplo en drawables .xml, layouts, la definición de un valor o propiedad incorrecta en `/values`,etc.

Si este tiene algún error dentro de algún archivo de recurso, el archivo **R.java** el cual contiene los ids de los recursos que contiene tu proyecto no es generado, por esta razón ves `R`. en color rojo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Revisa tus recursos y soluciona los problemas que encuentres, con esto solucionarias el problema, ya que la clase `R.java` se generaría nuevamente.**

Comment: @jaroncascantePérez Un placer amigo, corregiste el problema?

Comment: @jaroncascantePérez Si la respuesta te fue de ayuda podrías seleccionarla como respuesta, claro es solo sugerencia ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias, sí pude solucionar el problema, me fuiste de mucha ayuda gracias @x4mp73r.

Comment: Holaaa a todos!
Pues a mí no me ha quitado las Rs rojas. Lo he intentado todo, limpiar el proyecto, hacer un rebuild, invalidar la caché y, finalmente, revisar los recursos. Pero en ningún recurso me pintaba nada en rojo porque no había nada mal. También intenté cerrar Android y volver a abrirlo, pero nada.
Era un proyecto antiguo que me funcionaba estupendamente, pero al volver a sincronizar como sugería con el nuevo android studio, se me fastidió y no he podido recuperarlo.
¿Podríais ayudarme?
POR FAVOR!!!

Comment: @user101726 Claro que si , te ayudamos agrega tu pregunta, ¿tienes un repositorio de tu proyecto?