# Métodos de objeto R (R.java) no existen Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estaba programando, usando continuamente el método (R.layout.activity_main); sin ningún problema, pero repentinamente me da error, sugiriendo que el objeto no existe. ¿A qué se debe esto?

Tras resincronizar el proyecto y el .gradle el problema el objeto R sí que existe pero no sus métodos, indicando, por ejemplo, en la línea citada al principio "can´t resolve symbol 'layout'".

Comment: ¿No hay ningún error?

Comment: Revisa que no haya errores en los ficheros de la carpeta layout

Answer (score 2):

Suele coincidir con que se esté recompilando, o que haya algún error en el proyecto que impida que se haya compilado correctamente. Revisa el proyecto en busca de errores, tanto en java como en ficheros de `layout`.

Answer (score 1):

El archivo R.java el cual indicas es generado automáticamente, si se encuentra algun problema en alguno de los recursos, ya sea layouts o nombres no permitidos de recursos, este no se generarìa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Revisa tus recursos y soluciona los problemas que encuentres, con esto solucionarias el problema, ya que la clase `R.java` se generaría nuevamente.**

Revisa esta pregunta:

[Android, "R's" rojas en todo el código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34417/android-rs-rojas-en-todo-el-c%C3%B3digo/34434#34434)