# error with mainactivity.java

Tags: android, android-studio, xml

Error de carpetas y en el mainActivity también error. 
me señala una clase (R.)La cual no me permite acceder al id de un xml 
A continuación los errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error parece indicar que no has incluido tu librería `support/v7`. Para futuras preguntas, en vez de una imagen coloca el texto del código y el texto del error que te está dando. Es más fácil para visualizar y para poder hacer pruebas. Con una imagen no se puede hacer nada, y los usuarios que quieran responderte desde un dispositivo móvil la tendrán muy pero muy difícil.

Comment: File-> invalidate cache and restart, tiene pinta de ser alguna tontería del android studio

Answer (score 1):

### **Explicación archivo R.java**

---

El fichero R.java es generado automáticamente por el compilador. Se trata de una clase llena de variables estáticas en las que se identifica cada tipo de recurso.

Todas estas estructuras XML de los recursos serán leídas cuando la aplicación arranque, pero al encontramos en una plataforma móvil el trabajo con XML directo podría ser demoledor y lento. Por lo tanto Android después de leer el fichero XML carga todas las estructuras que se han solicitado en memoria y mantiene el fichero R como referencia directa a los recursos que se han cargado de esta manera el acceso será directo y sencillo para el programador.

El archivo R.java tendrá la siguiente estructura que se muestra en la imagen, en la que se pueden diferenciar los distintos tipos de recursos, como son: **attr, dimen, drawable, layout, etc**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Más información sobre el archivo R](http://www.arquitecturajava.com/android-r-java/)

### **Solución**

---

El problema de no poder generar la clase R.java o de que aparezca algún error con dicha clase es debido generalmente a que existe un error en los recursos, en los que no puede crear la referencia del id del recurso en dicha clase o también puede darse el caso que sólo se necesite limpiar el proyecto, por lo que te aconsejaría realizar los siguientes pasos

Realiza una limpieza de tu proyecto mediante:

```
Build > Clean Project
```

y posteriormente vuelve a construirlo con:

```
Build > Rebuild Project
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente asegura tengas definida la dependencia de la librería de soporte v7 dentro de tu `build.grade`, bloque `dependencies` :

```
dependencies {
    ...
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    ...
    ...
}
```

Si esta definida pero te indica que no esta instalada puedes dar click en los mensajes que indican instalar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cuanto a el archivo `R.java`, te sugiero revises algún posible problema en los recursos, es importante señalar que en ocasiones estos problemas no se muestran por lo que sugiero limpies tu proyecto mediante `Build` > `Clean Project`

esta es una pregunta relacionada a este problema:

[Android, "R's" rojas en todo el código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34417/android-rs-rojas-en-todo-el-c%C3%B3digo/34434#34434)

---

Como extra tienes un detalle que provocará problema, si usas el método `findViewById()`,

```
ediNombre=(EditText) findViewById();
```

debes especificar el id del elemento en el layout que cargas, en este caso el cargado mediante `setContentView()` que es `activity_main.xml` :

```
ediNombre=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.<especifica el id de la vista>);
```

Comment: Vale muchas gracias a todos, e podido solucionar. efectivamente era un error de dependencia de libreria ...compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'  Gracias

Comment: @Danserver un placer, saludos!