# Error android.R

Tags: android, android-studio

Hola cuando abro android studio las R se me ponen rojas y se me abre el archivo values.XML

y me salen unos errores como puedo solucionar esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: dale un clean y reconstruye tu proyecto y compila de nuevo.

Comment: Alejandro, te sugiero revisar en el sitio, tal vez lo que preguntes ya existe, en este caso existe un problema en los recursos, en este caso no puedes definir una propiedad con valor "" , https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34417/android-rs-rojas-en-todo-el-c%C3%B3digo/34434#34434

Comment: Aprovecho Alejandro para invitarte a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! para que obtengas buenas respuestas, te sugiero leer [ask], saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con las opciones del Android Studio

```
Build -> Rebuild Project 
Build > Clean Project
```

Comment: A mi no me funciona esto