# Númerosos errores en R por cambiar la version de Gradle (ANDROID STUDIO)

Tags: android-studio

buenas noches.

Vengo a esta pagina con un serio problema con el android studio. ¿Qué exactamente  es?:

Resulta que estoy desarrollando una app, y al terminar de corregir unos errores despúes de mucho tiempo, finalmente le presto atencion a las constantes sugerencias del android studio de actualizar el IDE. Yo obedientemente hago caso y empiezo a actualizar (Android Studio 3.0).... todo bien.

Cuando abro mi proyecto que estaba trabajando, el IDE me sugiere cambiarme de version del gradle para poder utilizar el instant run y demas funciones...

***Mi peor error... hacerle caso.***

Ahora el android studio me suelta cantidades de errores inexplicables en mi archivo **AndroidManifest.xml**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en mis clases tengo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Y de nuevo les juro:** no he tocado nada el codigo, simplemente lo que el IDE hizo fue cambiar la versión del gradle a 3.0.0 porque segun dicen, es una practica "recomendada".

Como soluciono yo este dolor de cabeza con este IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regularmente las R´s de color rojo indican que existe algún problema en los recursos.

[Android, "R's" rojas en todo el código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34417/android-rs-rojas-en-todo-el-c%C3%B3digo/34434#34434)

pero en este caso si revisas detenidamente el archivo que muestra tu mensaje de error, es el archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`, pero en este caso el que se encuentra dentro de `/build` que contiene los archivos generados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que presentas es común al realizar una actualización de nuestro Android Studio o sus componentes, en este caso el realizar :

`Build` > `Clean Project`

`Build` > `Rebuild Project`

puede no funcionar...

**Lo recomendado es invalidar caché y reiniciar Android Studio.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En realidad no es un error actualizar, de hecho lo que sugiere Android Studio es actualizar a las últimas versiones estables, para poder aprovechar las últimas características.

Comment: Me acaba de pasar esto mismo, por mucho que haga clean, rebuild y demás me siguen aparenciendo errores en las R

Answer (score 0):

Debes volver a construir el proyecto, cuando Android Studio no te detecte las "R" ve a `Build -> Clean Project` y después `Build -> Rebuild Project` y se solucionarán al menos los problemas de `Cannot Resolve symbol`

Comment: A mi esto no me soluciona nada. ¿ Qué mas opciones hay @Orz