# Problema con la clase R en Android Studio

Tags: android

Buenas, después de actualizar android studio en windows, siempre marca en rojo R.layout.activity_casilla_verificacion y todas las R de la actividad y no podemos solucionarlo, el layout esta bien escrito.

Comment: Intenta->Build->Clearn y luego Build->Rebuild Project

Comment: Adrián te sugiero realices  tus preguntas en base al documento [ask], trata de añadir más detalles, actualizar a que versión? tu proyecto funcionaba sin problema antes de actualizar?, has revisado algún problema en layouts?. También revisa el sitio ya se tiene información de esto.

Comment: Esto ya fue preguntado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/113296/n%C3%BAmerosos-errores-por-cambiar-la-version-de-gradle-android-studio

Comment: En la version 2.3 de Android Studio me pasaba muy seguido lo mismo de las R en rojo. yo lo solucione con "Clean project" o "Rebuild project" o tan simple como ejecutar el proyecto en el emulador o dispositivo y listo.

Comment: Hola la mitad de los casos se resueven con clean y Rebuild project pero hay otros casos donde si tienes un error en el codigo yo sugiero que mieres el error que da cuando lo ejecutas muchas veces ahi da una pista del xml o la clase que esta el problema lo otro es que abras todos los xml y todas las clases creadas en culquiera de esas puede estar el error y solo se pronuncia al abrirlo se pone rojo el error. en mi caso yo tenia el error en el archivo manifests ahi estaba haciendo una llamda a un titulo que estaba en el xml llamado string pero yo sin querer lo habia borrado al volverlo a poner a

Comment: Se soluciona sincronizando el proyecto.
Opción 2, limpiar y reconstruir el proyecto.

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer es algo habitual, a mi se me suele arreglar reiniciando Android Studio o el Pc y después entrando en el proyecto forzando una "rebuild" del proyecto.

Haciendo Click en "Rebuild project"

[image: Haciendo Click en Rebuild proyect]

Comment: No todos lo errores se solucionan con este método, hay que revisar si tenemos errores en los recursos o dependencias.

Comment: @Jorgesys me pasa lo mismo con la R y no consigo solucionarlo.