# Error en build.gradle "should not contain a package statement

Tags: android-studio, build

Ayer guarde todo y hoy cuando abro el proyecto me dice este error. Nunca lo ví y no se que podrá ser. Creo que a `fontprovidercerts` le faltan algunos caracteres pero la verdad que no se cuales son. Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

```
    /* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
    *
    * This class was automatically generated by the
    * gradle plugin from the resource data it found. It
    * should not be modified by hand.
    */
    package android.support.customview;

    public final class R {
    private R() {}

    public static final class attr {
        private attr() {}

        public static final int alpha = 0x7f030027;
        public static final int font = 0x7f0300d7;
        public static final int fontProviderAuthority = 0x7f0300d9;
        public static final int fontProviderCerts = 0x7f0
    }
}
```

Comment: Cual era el id que debería tener fontProviderCerts ?

Comment: Ninguno. Cuando reseteas el cache te aparece un texto completamente distinto. Eso ni aparece. No se que habrá pasado. Igual 30 minutos despues de publicar me pidio actualiacion el android studio. Y se soluciono todo. Para mi era por eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La clase es automáticamente generada y no debería ser modificada de forma manual.
lo que puedes hacer es: 
click en `File -> Invalidate cache and restart`

Luego click en `Build -> Rebuild project`

Comment: Gracias se solucionó. Y aparece un código totalmente distinto al que estaba. No tengo idea por que habrá pasado. Pero bueno solucionado gracias.

Comment: probablemente cuando lo abriste no cargo todas las dependencias por eso la necesidad de limpiar cache y reconstruir el proyecto

Answer (score 1):

En realidad lo que de sucedió es que posiblemente tenías un nombre de recurso incorrecto

**Recuerda que la nomenclatura de recursos, únicamente se permiten archivos con nombres que contengan caracteres en letra minúscula de "a" a la "z" y numéricos de 0 a 9.**

Si definiste un nombre no permitido no te permitirá construir el proyecto hasta que sea corregido.

si ya se encuentra corregido simplemente construye nuevamente el proyecto.

`Build` > `Rebuild project`

Si actualizaste Android Studio y tu proyecto funcionaba sin problema realiza

`File` > `Invalidate cache and restart`

Revisar:

[Númerosos errores en R por cambiar la version de Gradle (ANDROID STUDIO)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/113296/n%C3%BAmerosos-errores-en-r-por-cambiar-la-version-de-gradle-android-studio/113811#113811)

Comment: Gracias ya está solucionado. No era el nombre era que android studio requeria actualizacion

Comment: @Juampi Actualizaste Android Studio?