# Error en Values.xml

Tags: java, android, android-studio

tengo un pequeño error en values.xml Me dice esto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en el values.xml tengo esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien tengo un error en `setContentView(R.layout.activity_registro_usuarios);`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seguro que es muy facil de resolver el error, pero no encuentro la solución si alguien me hecha una mano.

Comment: puedes poner tu archivo  dimens.xml

Answer (score -3, accepted):

El problema indica que estas definiendo propiedades sin valor, en este caso `activity_vertical_margin` que regularmente se encuentra definido en el archivo `dimens.xml`, este es un ejemplo del archivo:

```
<!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="twitter_fnt_button">18dp</dimen>
<dimen name="twitter_fnt_charscount">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="email_txt_labels">16dp</dimen>
```

Debes definir un valor!

La razón por la cual se muestran R`s de color rojo es precisamente porque tienes errores en los recursos.

[Android, "R's" rojas en todo el código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34417/android-rs-rojas-en-todo-el-c%C3%B3digo)

Comment: Para los  -1 si están seguros que esta respuesta no es correcta @diegoveloper ,  al menos agreguen un comentario para debatirlo, si es que se tienen argumentos.