# aapt.exe finished with non-zero exit value 1 Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Actualicé mi Android Studio de la versión 2.3.3 a la versión 3.1. me dio varios problemas que fui solucionando. Sin embargo hay uno que me ha sido imposible. El error dice así:

```
Process 'command 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Falla en este punto:

[image]

He leído que hay dos posibles soluciones:

1. android.enableAapt2=false en gradle.properties. Esto no me funciona. Solo me muestra un warning al inicio.
2. Build->Clean project, Build->Rebuild Project Esto tampoco, me sigue saltando el mismo error.

Si alguien supiera que puede estar pasando. 
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a **Stack Overflow en español**, por favor traduce tu pregunta para dar una respuesta clara.

Comment: Ya está traducida

Comment: Revisa si hay alguna clase, o archivo axml con un nombre no válido. Que tenga espacio o algún simbolo extraño en el proyecto. Ese puede ser el problema, me ha pasado varias veces.

Comment: A mi me esta sucediendo exactamente lo mismo, cual seria la solución? Este error aparece luego de actualizar a la versión 3 de Android Studio.

Comment: @DiegoMontagud esto se debe a varias causas, cuando muestra "exit value 1"  esta relacionado generalmente a problema en los recursos. Revisa : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34417/android-rs-rojas-en-todo-el-c%C3%B3digo

Comment: @ManuelMeleán si funcionaba tu proyecto entonces solo elimina el caché, revisa mi respuesta, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

**Si tu proyecto funcionaba sin problema y realizaste una actualización de Android Studio**

debe ser suficiente con invalidar el caché de `Android Studio` mediante la opción:

`Invalidate Caches / Restart`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

El error que mencionas

> aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

esta relacionado esta relacionado también a un problema en los recursos, te sugiero revisar:

[Android, "R's" rojas en todo el código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34417/android-rs-rojas-en-todo-el-c%C3%B3digo)