# Error en consola google play: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx

He actualizado las librerías de mi app a androidx, también he actualizado a android studio 3.4.1. El código de mi aplicación no ha variado más que lo necesario para migrar a androidx.

Antes de estas modificaciones mi app no mostraba ningún bloqueo, al actualizarla aparece el siguiente error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3573)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 (ActivityThread.java:236)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1795)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7037)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver (AppComponentFactory.java:84)
  at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver (CoreComponentFactory.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3566)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 (ActivityThread.java:236)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1795)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7037)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Mi fichero build.grade

```
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 3
        versionName '1.0.3'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            useProguard false // <-- disable proguard
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'

    }
```

El problema afecta a diferentes dispositivos y versiones de Android.

Teniendo en cuenta que el error ha surgido tras la actualización debe ser algún problema de configuración pero no consigo dar con ello porque al probar la app no me aparece el error, por tanto no puedo reproducirlo, únicamente lo veo en la consola de google.

Comment: El problema que estas teniendo por el código que has puesto no te puedo decir el componente exacto que esta fallando pero se trata de un componente que requiere el appcompat con la versión que tenías antaño y no es válida para Androidx. Por lo que la solución viene encontrarlo y migrarlo a Androidx dicho parace fácil pero a mi me ha dado muchos dolores de cabeza en los proyectos que me ha pasado.

Comment: Hola @Mtoh como realizaste una actualización trata primeramente invalidando cache y reinicia https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/134633/aapt-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1-android-studio/221139#221139  comenta que resultados obtienes,

Comment: He invalidado cache, reiniciado, revisado todo el código y al subir la nueva version los problemas continúan. Lo peor es que no consigo reproducir el error. Los test que realizo en  firebase test Lab del informe previo al lanzamiento en la play console salen sin errores por lo que sigo sin ninguna pista de por donde buscar.

Answer (score 0):

He resuelto el problema gracias a la aportación de un usuario que me indico que para usar Admob 18.0.0 en AndroidX debía incluir en mi build.grade las líneas

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk:17.0.0
```

Revisé la información en https://developers.google.com/ y para mi sorpresa, como por defecto la página se muestra en español esta información no aparecía, sim embargo esta infromación si aparecía en la versión en inglés.

Estas líneas son únicamente necesarias para la versión 18.0.0 tal como aparece en las notas de las versiones https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rel-notes.