# Realicé Refactor y presento problema la clase R en Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy comenzando a desarrollar en Android y durante la creación del proyecto todo estaba marchando bien, cuando importo la clase R en los Activity la ruta de importación es la siguiente:

```
import com.example.corporation.bible_ebate.R
```

En el avance del proyecto decidí deshacerme del nombre que le coloque al package inicial, por lo cual realice un Refactor y ahora esta:

```
  corporation.bibledebate
```

Por ende ahora quiero que se importe R como:

```
  import corporation.bibledebate.R
```

Y no como estaba antes, pero no funciona, se sigue importando con el antiguo nombre, realice Clean, Rebuild , Reinicie , sin embargo no consigo que hacer para cambiar la ruta de importación, alguna idea lo agradecería.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Independiente de como realizaste el Refactor del paquete de la aplicación, tienes que asegurar principalmente 3 cosas para que tu proyecto funcione correctamente:

1) Dentro el archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` el paquete debe ser el que cambiaste

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="corporation.bibledebate">
```

2) Dentro de tu archivo `build.gradle` tu applicationid debe ser el package name:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "corporation.bibledebate"
    ...
     }
....
}
```

3)Revisa que en algún layout no tengas definido el package name anterior: "`com.example.corporation.bible_ebate`" , por ejemplo en Custom Views.

---

Recuerda que las R´s rojas indican un problema regularmente en los recursos, en este caso los layout que alguno de ellos puede tener definido el package name incorrecto:

[Android, "R's" rojas en todo el código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34417/android-rs-rojas-en-todo-el-c%C3%B3digo)

Comment: Excelente! Muchas Gracias logre hacerlo

Comment: Excelente noticia @SamuelHeredia , saludos!