# tengo un problema al momento de copilar en android studio y con el R.java

Tags: java, android-studio, ide

[image: como veran en la parte de abajo al momento de copilar el archivo o al momento de hacer el build>clean project y el build>rebuild project para solucionar lo de R.java sigue saliendo el error de java compiler]

Necesito ayuda ya que no puedo solucionar el problema de `R.java` y me sale un error de Build: `build failed` como pueden ver en la imagen y no se si eso tenga que ver con que no me aparece en ningun proyecto que abro la clase o referencia `R.java`.

Ademas ya intente hacer el *build>clean project* y el *build>rebuild project* para tratar de solucionar lo del `R.java` pero solo me sigue apareciendo el error que ven en la parte de abajo de la imagen y ya lo volvi a instalar como 3 veces y sigue sin arreglarse.

Antes de instalar el Android studio v3.1.1, instale el jdk 10 y el jdk 8 porque pense que era un problema del jdk pero nada. Instale java en mi pc justo como hay que hacer normalmente antes de instalar android studio, mi pc tiene windows 8.

Comment: Abre el directorio /main y revisa que archivos tienen error, se subrayan en rojo @Robertrr y comenta, en realida el problema de la R es porque tienes algún archivo con un problema: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34417/android-rs-rojas-en-todo-el-c%C3%B3digo

Comment: Agrega los **imports** del `MainActivity` a la pregunta.

Comment: A mi alguna vez me apareció y lo que hice fue buscar las librerías del proyecto y deshabilitar una que se llama `appcompactv7` o algo así y luego la volvía a habilitar; esa librería maneja el paquete `R`.

Comment: creo que lo que te hace falta es el import del R, pero como comenta @DavidMinaya, agrega los imports que tienes

Comment: Y como se deshabilita la librería? para ver si así se resuelve ya que me cambie de la versión 3.1.1 a la 3.0 y el problema sigue y la carpeta la carpeta que contiene el R.java no aparece