# Error en android studio compilacion

Tags: android-studio, xml

me sucede que en el día anterior tuve que apagar el equipo forzadamente y tenia android studio abierto, ya cuando lo abro no me quiere compilar bien. a que se debe esto?.. me ayudarían mucho 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Android, "R's" rojas en todo el código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34417/android-rs-rojas-en-todo-el-c%c3%b3digo)

Comment: gracias DevCodeG

Comment: Hola, podrias ir a File->Invalide Cache/Restart ->Invalide and Restart, espero que te ayude