# android studio :cuando quiero editar un layout aparece basura

Tags: android, android-studio

Soy nuevo en Android Studio y algunos comportamientos me ponen loco como el siguiente:

Hasta hace unos días en mi proyecto venia todo bien cuando encontré que al entrar a alguno de los xml del directorio layout en su contenido encontraba:

```
/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.

     *
     * This class was automatically generated by the
     * gradle plugin from the resource data it found. It
     * should not be modified by hand.
     */
    package com.google.android.gms.identity;

    public final class R {
    }
```

Lo cierto es que en realidad, si abro el archivo desde el explorador de Windows el contenido del archivo es correcto.

Ya invalidé caché, borré .idea y .gradle, clean y rebuild pero aún nada.

¿Cómo podría resolver esto?

Comment: No estás diciendo que querés lograr editando ese archivo. El archivo tampoco es un xml, y como dice el cartel, ese archivo se genera en forma automática. No hay motivo para editarlo a mano.

Comment: lo que quise significar que mientras el archivo real - que es un layout-tiene xml, al editarlo desde android studio aparece esa basura en el contenido. ahora me explico?

Comment: Hola @Roman qué tal, parece que es un error de esa versión pienso yo, te dejo este link de otra pregunta muy similar a la que tienes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52971000/error-with-the-code-in-java-classes-and-xml-files

Comment: @Roman No es ningún error de versión. El archivo se encuentra dentro de   \build\intermediates ? revisa en la barra superior de Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

> Hasta hace unos días en mi proyecto venia todo bien cuando encontré
> que al entrar a alguno de los xml del directorio layout en su
> contenido encontraba. Ya invalidé caché, borré .idea y .gradle, clean
> y rebuild pero aún nada.

Comentas que tu proyecto funcionaba correctamente, el problema que indicas puede provocarse por las siguientes causas.

- Error al sincronizar los ids de recursos.

En ocasiones el realizar `Clean`  > `Rebuild` puede no se suficiente, te aconsejo eliminar los folders `/build` con esto obligaras realmente a construir nuevamente tu proyecto.

- Existe algún problema con los recursos.

[Android, "R's" rojas en todo el código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34417/android-rs-rojas-en-todo-el-c%C3%B3digo)

- Veo que eliminaste los directorios  .idea y .gradle sin embargo lo recomendable en este caso es eliminar el caché y reiniciar.

  tienes que realizar la eliminación del caché mediante:

`File` -> `Invalidate Caches/Restart`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Mil gracias... sabes como resolvi ese problema? modificando la fecha en que fueron modificados los archivos xml. puede ser esa la razon del problema?

Otro problema contemporaneo que estoy teniendo es que en el diseñador de layouts no me aparecen todas las propiedades de los objetos.... sera por eso??

saludos, Roman