# Mi clase de vista no reconoce mi Layout XML (Cannot find symbol) - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml, android-layout

Cree una actividad nueva en mi proyecto de Android Studio, pero al momento de crearla, me dice que no puede encontar en archivo XML, pero es el mismo que me generó el mismo IDE.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de ver las sugerencias solamente me aparece esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Haz un Clean al código y reinicia el Android Studio

Comment: ¡Gracias! quien lo diría.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que comentas es "raro", si en realidad no se muestran errores en el recurso, en este caso `activity_informacion.xml`

[Android, "R's" rojas en todo el código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34417/android-rs-rojas-en-todo-el-c%C3%B3digo)

Si el archivo .xml tuviera un error, esa sería la causa del problema que presentas, **en este caso si no tiene error simplemente es un error de sincronización de los archivos generados al construir tu proyecto.**

Limpia el proyecto y construyelo nuevamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en ocasiones he experimentado que esto no corrige el problema en versiones de Android Studio 3.1 o anteriores, en este caso puedes eliminar los directorio `/build` de tu proyecto.