# Error R en android studio para Mac

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

Tengo un problema con el error de la R en android, sin embargo es curioso porque solo me muestra el error cuando abro el proyecto desde una Mac

Ya intente un clean proyect y rebuild proyect, pero persiste el problema igual he revisado mi XML en busca del error pero no he notada nada raro.

Mi proyecto funcionaba bien, compila y puedo probarlo pero nunca deja de aparecer el error en R

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Igual comparto mi código espero me puedan ayudar

Login.Class

```
package com.xteam.ahorroink;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.*;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText user,pass;
    private Cursor fila;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        //emperejamos las variable con el xml
        user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txbuserlogin);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txbpasslogin);
    }

    public void Ingresar(View v) {
        String usuario = String.valueOf(user.getText());
        String password = String.valueOf(pass.getText());
        //String usuario = user.getText().toString();
        //String password = pass.getText().toString();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(usuario)) {
            user.setError("Por favor ingresa tu usuario");
            user.requestFocus();

            return;
        } if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            pass.setError("Por favor ingresa tu contraseña");
            pass.requestFocus();

            return;
        }

        StringRequest postRequest1 = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i("mensaje", response);

                try {
                    //Convertimos el response a un objeto Json
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    String errorResp = obj.getString("error");

                    if (Integer.parseInt(errorResp) == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Bienvenido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        //starting the profile activity
                        Intent menu = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(menu);

                        //limpiamos las las cajas de texto
                        user.setText("");
                        pass.setText("");
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch(JSONException ex) {
                    String msg = ex.getMessage().toString();
                    Log.d("mensaje", msg);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("mensaje", error.toString());
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error de comunicación: comprueba tu conexión\"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(postRequest1);
    }

    public void Registro(View v) {
        Intent ven = new Intent(Login.this,Registro.class);
        startActivity(ven);
    }
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Login">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txbuserlogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/title_login_user"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txbpasslogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:hint="@string/title_login_pass"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btmsalirlogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:onClick="Ingresar"
            android:text="@string/title_login_login" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtregistro1login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/title_txtreg1_login"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtregistrologin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:onClick="Registro"
        android:text="@string/title_txtreg2_login"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Alguna Sugerencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las R`s Rojas significan generalmente un problema en los recursos:

[Android, "R's" rojas en todo el código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34417/android-rs-rojas-en-todo-el-c%C3%B3digo)

pero en este caso comentas que el proyecto funciona sin problema hasta que lo abres desde una MAC, en este caso no deberías tener ningún problema pero cuando lo copias a otro equipo, **lo recomendable es que elimines los directorio `/build` de tu proyecto antes de abrir tu proyecto en otra compadora.**

Comment: Gracias en este caso si me funciono.