# Porque no me funciona la carpeta res

Tags: android, android-studio

El problema que tengo con este proyecto es que el programa no me reconoce la R refiriendome a la carpeta res y el error que me muestra es que no puede resolver el simbolo R.
Este es mi codigo:
package com.example.menuoverflow;

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    //Método para mostrar y ocultar el menú
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.overflow, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //Método para asignar las funciones correspondientes a las opciones.
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == R.id.item1){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Opción 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if(id == R.id.item2){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Opción 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if(id == R.id.item3){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Opción 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Entra en Build>Clean Project y sino funciona prueba con Build>Rebuild Project

Comment: pero en que linea de codigo te marca error?

Comment: en todas las que contienen una R mayuscula

Comment: Hola @Jorge te sugiero agregues una imagen de como se muestran tus layouts,Tienes un problema en recursos : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34417/android-rs-rojas-en-todo-el-c%C3%B3digo , te sugiero revises esta pregunta para cerrar la que realizaste como duplicado.

Comment: revisa todos los xml(layout, drawable, strings) que no contengan errores

Answer (score 1):

No es la carpeta res la que no te reconoce, esa `R` hace referencia a una clase propia de `android`, para solventar el problema:

```
1- click en el menu Build
2- click en Clean Project
3- click en Build Project
```

Si lo anterior no funciona prueba con:

```
1- click en el menu File 
2- Invalidates Cache /restart
```

Comment: Correcto. Estaba buscando en el código algo sobre la carpeta `res` y no aparece nada referido a ello. Parece que ha creído que `R` se refiere específicamente a esa carpeta. Creo que conviene añadir a tu respuesta [este enlace](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#Accessing) que explica el funcionamiento de los recursos, y el enlace a la [clase `R`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R).

Comment: Muchas gracias a Igmer Rodrigez y  A. Cedano por contestar pero me he estado leyendo los enlaces que me has dicho pero sigo sin entender porque no me lo reconoce lo he mirado en internet formas de arreglar este error pero no me ha funcionado ninguna. Si supieseis alguna otra forma me las podriais comentar Muchas gracias.