# ¿Cómo puedo usar el AAPT en Android?

Tags: java, android

tengo el siguiente problema: Estoy intentando crear un IDE... Pero no sé construir el APK generado desde mi aplicación, investigando me he dado cuenta de que esto es posible a una herramienta llamada "aapt". ¿Cómo lo hago?

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español, mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funciona el sitio y de paso obtener tu primera medalla. Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido, te invitamos a reviasr [ask], modifica tu pregunta, El AAPT contribuye en la construcciòn del .APK pero no "compila los archivos XML", te sugiero agregues que es lo que realizas, que error se muestra por favor, saludos.

Comment: Lo que comentas no tiene mucho sentido, el problema es en el proyecto , probablemente tienes errores en el còdigo o los recursos, revisa: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34417/android-rs-rojas-en-todo-el-c%c3%b3digo?r=SearchResults&s=1|49.9626