# Error al usar Android Studio: "Error: Please select Android SDK"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, sdk

He estado usando Android Studio por un tiempo. Hace una semana decidí actualizarlo a la versión 4.1 (si no recuerdo mal), no actualizaba desde hace meses.

Desde que lo actualicé, soy incapaz de hacer nada. No puedo acceder a la ventana de diseño (de los .xml), y tampoco puedo compilar mi app. También me aparece esto:

[image: El botón de app tiene una x roja delante]

El error que recibo es el siguiente:

> Please select Android SDK.

Aún así, sí tengo el SDK instalado y en el "Project Manager" tengo la dirección correcta.

[image: Dirección]

He visto que a varios les pasa lo mismo, pero ninguna de las soluciones encontradas en internet ni en este foro me ha servido. He intentado, por ejemplo, borrar la caché del programa, o hacer "Sync Project with Gradle Files". Nada de eso sirve. También lo desinstalé y volví a instalar, algo que siempre funciona, pero tampoco.

También creé otro programa, para ver si era problema del proyecto activo, pero no.

Ojalá alguien tenga alguna solución, pues me gustaría seguir desarrollando la app en la que estaba trabajando, y de repente se hizo imposible.

Muchísimas gracias, de verdad.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes el Android SDK instalado entonces ve a `File` > `Project Structure` , selecciona `SDK Location` y ahí define la ruta en donde se encuentra el Android SDK

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos, lamentablemente ya hice eso varias veces. La ruta es correcta, aún así me salta el error.

Comment: Actualicé la pregunta incluyendo captura de lo que tengo en la ruta asignada al sdk.

Comment: Veo que te muestra esto https://i.stack.imgur.com/tk3ul.png o tienes un problema en recursos o dependencias o simplemente es un error de sincronización, realiza File > Invalidates Cache / Restart @Tupi

Comment: Saludos, el `File > Invalidates Cache / Restart` lo hice y no solucionó nada. Si es un problema en recursos o dependencias, ¿cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Estas seguro que antes de actualizar funcionaba sin probemas tu proyecto @Tupi ?, si funcionaba y actualizaste esto debió resolver el problema. Debes revisar las clases si se marcan en rojo o los recursos para encontrar el problema, revisa: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34417/android-rs-rojas-en-todo-el-c%c3%b3digo

Comment: Sí, justo antes de actualizar funcionaba perfectamente. He revisado y tengo las clases bien. No tengo idea de porqué está fallando.

Answer (score 0):

yo tuve una solución, fue algo breve; donde esta el sdk se debe  eliminar o mejor dicho desinstala y lo vuelve instalar.

otra opción volver instalar  Android. un tiempo estuve  desarrollando con flutter, al principio me pasaba esto.

recuerda guardar tus proyectos antes de desinstalar

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).