# LayoutInflater no reconoce id de archivo xml

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion de tareas con Kotlin y Android Studio. El problema es que, en el BaseAdapter, concretamente en la funcion getView, no me reconoce los id de el archivo tareas.xml y no entiendo por qué.

Este es mi archivo tareas.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titulo_tarea"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="60dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/descripcion_tarea"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="60dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="56dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Y este es el BaseAdapter (TareasAdapter.kt). Lo he marcado para que sepan que es esa la línea que me da el error

```
package com.example.listadetareas

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.BaseAdapter

class TareasAdapter(
var context: Context,
var lista_tareas: MutableList<ObjetoTarea>


): BaseAdapter() {


override fun getCount(): Int {
    return lista_tareas.size
}

override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
    return position
}

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return position.toLong()
}

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    var layout = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tareas, null)

    **layout.titulo_tarea**

    return layout
 }
}
```

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te refieres a que te da error en línea `layout.titulo_tarea` es porque esa no es la forma de acceder a los elementos de un layout. A menos que uses [view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) o algo similar, tienes que usar `findViewById()` para acceder a ellos

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    var layout = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tareas, null)
    val tituloTarea = layout.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.titulo_tarea)
    ...
    return layout
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

El archivo del layout `tareas.xml` debe encontrarse dentro de la estructura de directorios `res/layout/`. Si el archivo se encuentra entonces el problema es simplemente de sincronización por esa razón no reconoce el id.

Si el problema es de sincronización simplemente `Build` > `Rebuild Project` y aquí debes asegurar no tengas errores en algún recurso ya que esto pudiera haber detenido la sincronización (Revisa [Android, “R's” rojas en todo el código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34417/android-rs-rojas-en-todo-el-c%C3%B3digo)  ).